# ArrayList<recipe> to JList

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jlist

I have multiple recipes which I want the user to chose from (JList) and then it will show the ingredients of the recipe in another JList.

I want the recipe JList to show the name of the recipe only.
So basically I need to understand how to make a JList out of a ArrayList and show only one attribute of the object, for instance the name.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like so: `recepies= new JList(recepiesList.toArray())`.

Then, in your `Recipe` class, override the `toString()` method to show what ever field it is you want to show.